# How to display chinese characters in cxGrid

Tags: text, character, tcxgrid

I've got a DB in Cinese and a cxGrid connected to it. The chinese digits are displayed as '?' in grid. I tied to change the grid's CharSet but had no success. Could you help me out, pleese?